# Lightweight linux desktop with UI scaling

Tags: linux, linux-distribution

I am looking for a lightweight linux desktop to use as an [Home Theatre PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_theater_PC), that has UI scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) for that. It is a lightweight distro based on Ubuntu with a minimalistic UI and HiDPI support. Although, it seems like they are using a workaround for [this](https://medium.com/elementaryos/what-is-hidpi-and-why-does-it-matter-b024eabea20d), according to one of the designers. ("update" paragraph, before the "takeaway" list).
[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/53gkr1/elementary_os_loki_hidpi_experience_and_tips/) is another discussion on that subject.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might try Linux [Window Managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers) such as Fluxbox or OpenBox.

If you want to install Fluxbox, first install [Ubuntu Mini](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), then install window manager and login manager:

```
sudo apt-get install fluxbox xorg slim
```

Then open console by right clicking desktop: Applications > Shell > Bash

Type `xrandr` to see options, type `xrandr -s 1920x1200` to change resolution. Mplayer is a good video player which you can start from console.

[askubuntu.com - What is the difference between a desktop environment and a window manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-desktop-environment-and-a-window-manager#20435)